# Can not deserialize instance of Bean out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

While doing request from serviceA to serviceB,

the test request in serviceA is

```
    public void testGet(){
        MYBean[] beans= template.getForObject("http://localhost:8022/service/testGet", MYBean[].class);
        List<MYBean> list = Arrays.asList(beans);
    }
```

The result comming from serviceB is queried from DB and excactly the same JSON string.

Now strange things happened:

the exactly same response some times will pass successfully with 200 OK, and sometimes receive an exception with code 500.

Here is what I received from serviceB RestTemplate request and logged in serviceA.

````
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@30877129; line: 1, column: 1]```
````

Answer (score 0):

WTF,serviceB shows that Loadbalancer cannot find one of the host of a hidden dependency of serviceC and leads to a exception. The error log is not printed in the logfile...problem solved.